# Define a new coordinate chart and do algebra/calculus in it

Tags: symbolic, coordinate-transformation

I've stumbled across a very nasty problem: define a toroidal coordinate chart and calculate Laplacian in it. As I'm going through it manually, I wonder if this can't be made in Mathematica. Sure, MMA has no toroidal coordinates, but we can define ones:

```
x[ν_, u_, ϕ_] := {a Sinh[ν]/(Cosh[ν] - Cos[u]) Cos[ϕ],
                  a Sinh[ν]/(Cosh[ν] - Cos[u]) Sin[ϕ],
                  a Sin[u]/(Cosh[ν] - Cos[u])};
```

Now the first thing to do is to find scaling factors and unit vectors:

```
ClearAll[scale];
scale[ν_, u_, ϕ_] := scale[ν, u, ϕ] = 
   Abs@FullSimplify[ Norm /@ {Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][ν, u, ϕ],
            Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][ν, u, ϕ], Derivative[0, 0, 1][x][ν, u, ϕ]},
                     Assumptions -> {a > 0, ν > 1, u > 0, u < 2 π, ϕ > 0, ϕ < 2 π}];
```

However, this works without flaws only with symbolic values. If numbers are fed to this, MMA may produce an error about Assumptions (because you cannot have assumptions that evaluate to false). However, without assumptions you get some huge expressions with Norm and squared Abs, which is not really useful if you just want a simple expression. **This needs correction.** A possible one is adding one line:

```
scale[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  scale[ν, u, ϕ] /. {ν -> x, u -> y, ϕ -> z};
```

Now MMA is capable of producing results both with symbolic values and numbers. I bet this can be done in somewhat nicer manner, but I'm no MMA pro.

Once we have the scaling factors we can proceed on with the unit vectors

```
ClearAll[unit];
unit[ν_, u_, ϕ_] := unit[ν, u, ϕ] = 
   FullSimplify[Thread[Divide[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][ν, u, ϕ], 
       Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][ν, u, ϕ], Derivative[0, 0, 1][x][ν, u, ϕ]}, 
      scale[ν, u, ϕ]], 1], Assumptions -> {a > 0, ν > 1, u > 0, u < 2 π, ϕ > 0, ϕ < 2 π}];
unit[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  unit[ν, u, ϕ] /. {ν -> x, u -> y, ϕ -> z};
```

Of course, it is wise to check for the orthogonality of the unit vectors...

```
Outer[Dot, unit[ν, u, ϕ], unit[ν, u, ϕ], 1]
{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Yes, unit vectors are orthogonal and normalized.

Now, I'm interested in the following matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \hat{\nu} & \hat{u} & \hat{\phi}
\end{pmatrix} = ?
$$
i.e. all possible derivatives of all possible unit vectors (results are ofc expressible in cartesian basis $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$ or toroidal basis $\hat{\nu}, \hat{u}, \hat{\phi}$).

We can find it like this:

```
M = {Transpose@unit[ν, u, ϕ].Derivative[1, 0, 0][unit][ν, u, ϕ],
   Transpose@unit[ν, u, ϕ].Derivative[0, 1, 0][unit][ν, u, ϕ],
   Transpose@unit[ν, u, ϕ].Derivative[0, 0, 1][unit][ν, u, ϕ]} // Simplify
```

The torture is not done yet. I want find the divergence of a general vector field $A$

```
A[ν_, u_, ϕ_] := unit[ν, u, ϕ].{A1[ν, u, ϕ], A2[ν, u, ϕ], A3[ν, u, ϕ]};
```

From the above it seems it is

```
Simplify[({1/scale[ν, u, ϕ][[1]], 0, 0}.Transpose@unit[ν, u, ϕ].D[A[ν, u, ϕ], ν]
    + {0, 1/scale[ν, u, ϕ][[2]], 0}.Transpose@unit[ν, u, ϕ].D[A[ν, u, ϕ], u]                                 
    + {0, 0, 1/scale[ν, u, ϕ][[3]]}.Transpose@unit[ν, u, ϕ].D[A[ν, u, ϕ], ϕ]),
    Assumptions -> {a > 0, ν > 1, u > 0, u < 2 π, ϕ > 0, ϕ < 2 π}]
```

The final goal for me is to find the Laplacian, which is divergence of gradient of some function

```
ClearAll[f, gradf]
gradf[ν_, u_, ϕ_] := gradf[ν, u, ϕ] = 
   Simplify[ Grad[f[ν, u, ϕ], {ν, u, ϕ}].unit[ν, u, ϕ], 
    Assumptions -> {a > 0, ν > 1, u > 0, u < 2 π, ϕ > 0, ϕ < 2 π}];
```

And finally, Laplacian

```
Simplify[({1/scale[ν, u, ϕ][[1]], 0, 0}.Transpose@
     unit[ν, u, ϕ].D[gradf[ν, u, ϕ], ν] + {0, 
     1/scale[ν, u, ϕ][[2]], 0}.Transpose@
     unit[ν, u, ϕ].D[gradf[ν, u, ϕ], u] + {0, 0, 
     1/scale[ν, u, ϕ][[3]]}.Transpose@
     unit[ν, u, ϕ].D[gradf[ν, u, ϕ], ϕ]), 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, ν > 1, u > 0, 
   u < 2 π, ϕ > 0, ϕ < 2 π}]
```

However I'm not sure this is entirely correct (probably not lol) and I want to do this more effectively, faster and universally. For example, how to do this so that I would only write down the initial parametrization and Mathematica would spit out all subsequent results, mainly `Div`, `Grad` and `Laplacian` operators so that I don't have to worry about retyping everything...I hope it's clear what I want to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: What version are you using? After MMA 9.0, it provides toroidal coordinates: `CoordinateTransformData[
 "Toroidal" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping", {u, v, \[Phi]}]`. So you can do vectorial analysis safely in this coordinate system...

Comment: Two questions: what if I want another set of toroidal coordinates, ones defined as x=(c+r cos theta) cos phi, y = (c+r cos theta) sin phi, z = r sin theta? And everything calculated in these coordinates? Second question: how do I recover unit vectors, scale factors, derivatives of unit vectors etc. from what you offered?

Comment: Your definitions correspond to a standard toroidal coordinates, it seems to me. Otherwise, you must follow the general procedure of vectorial analysis via metric tensor and so on...I have not read carefully your question.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, in my question I stated different parametrization than in my last comment. Mathematica knows the first one.